# How to not add values from Join

Tags: sql

```
SELECT ...

FROM [Rep_GroupNode] C                                    

left join                                                   
(SELECT ....
```

if I'm using left join only for compare some thing due selecting how to not add(double) values from join ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're encountering a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

Example:

```
Rep_GroupNode    MappingTable
-------------    ------------------------
id    name       id    rgn_id    rgn_type
1     a          1     1         type1
2     b          2     1         type2
3     c          3     2         type1
```

So a join on `Rep_GroupNode.id = MappingTable.rgn_id` returns two (2) records for `Rep_GroupNode.id = 1`

Some methods to handle this are mentioned in the other good answers, but for a definitive answer we'd need more information about what your data look like and exactly what information you'd like to project from it.

Here's an example (based on my sample data) of another method to avoid returning duplicate records:

```
   SELECT rgn.*
     FROM Rep_GroupNode rgn
LEFT JOIN MappingTable mt ON mt.rgn_id = rgn.id
      AND mt.rgn_type = 'type1'
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `LEFT JOIN`, you can select only the `DISTINCT` values of those columns you are joining on.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2
          FROM   Table2
        ) Table2 ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
                    AND Table1.Col2 = Table2.Col2
```

Answer (score 1):

Then just write

```
SELECT C.* FROM [Rep_GroupNode] C LEFT JOIN (SELECT x, y, z FROM TableB B) ON ...
WHERE C.ReferenceID = B.ID
```

This should do what you would like to get... but also possible:

```
SELECT C.* FROM [Rep_GroupNode] C, [TableB] B WHERE C.ReferenceID = B.ID
```

Comment: in effect, you are using an INNER JOIN. I don't think that that was what OP was looking for. All records from Rep_GroupNode should get returned.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little bit unspecific... but the request was also... so this could be taken as a hint how to solve unless we get more informations. :-)